# ASP.Net membership provider

Tags: asp.net, linq, membership-provider

I have a couple of questions regarding Membership Provider.  My textbook got me started but I still need more information.

1. I am using Linq to Entities, does it make sense to also create LINQ entity relationships with my membership provider DB?
2. I would like to add additional user attributes other than provided in the membership provider.  Can I add them to the aspnet.USER table without any issues?

My users will join the website and will gain privildges as they participate, much like Stack Overflow.  I want to keep track of their postings by adding a field to the user table to manage that function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you want to store profile information in the user table.  Have you looked at the Profile Provider?  Here's an example: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/19/writing-a-custom-asp-net-profile-class.aspx

Answer (score 2):

> There are two ways to associate additional information with user accounts when using the Membership model. The first - which affords the greatest flexibility, but requires the most upfront effort - is to create a custom data store for this information. If you are using the SqlMembershipProvider, this would mean creating an additional database table that had as a primary key the UserId value from the aspnet_Users table and columns for each of the additional user properties. In the online messageboard example, the table might be called forums_UserProfile and have columns like UserId (a primary key and a foreign key back to aspnet_Users.UserId), HomepageUrl, Signature, and IMAddress.
>
> Rather than using custom data stores, the ASP.NET Profile system can
>   be used to store user-specific information. The Profile system allows
>   the page developer to define the properties she wants to associate
>   with each user. Once defined, the developer can programmatically read
>   from and assign values to these properties. The Profile system
>   accesses or writes the property values to a backing store as needed.
>   Like Membership and Roles, the Profile system is based on the provider
>   model, and the particular Profile provider is responsible for
>   serializing and deserializing the property values to some data store.
>   The .NET Framework ships with a SqlProfileProvider class by default,
>   which uses a SQL Server database table (aspnet_Profile) as its backing
>   store.

[Examining ASP.NET's Membership, Roles, and Profile - Part 6
By Scott Mitchell](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111657/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/101106-1.aspx)

This should get you started. I guess I could answer your questions as follow:

1. It shouldn't be necessary. Explore the membership API, everything you ever wanted is... *probably* in there.
2. Read the article and decide what's best.

Good luck, :).

Sincerely,
Maxime